# Dev version of ESPHOME missing libraries?

Tags: home-assistant

My ESPHOME (DEV edition 1.14.0) installation on my Home Assistant Lovelace setup (RPi) is showing spurious apparently CSS-related stuff on the main screen. On the log, I see the following:[image: ESPHome Log]

Any idea what I can do about this?

Comment: Found it to be a bug in HA. Described on Github issues page. Expect it to be solved in a future release.